# How to hide light shape source through transparent window in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, transparency

Shape of area light becomes visible through the transparent window in Blender Cycles.
I would like to keep the lighting effects, but hide the source shape.
On 1st screen: we can see the steam and droplet I want to keep
2nd screen : unchecking transmission disable all lighting through window.
3rd screen : window is hidden; square shape is not rendered.

Any help will be appreciated !

[image: cycles light shape]

Comment: Can you share your file on [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? Not clear how the various components are constructed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys!
Light path does the job for mesh emitter, but not for the light.
It will be ok for this one.
Here is a scene with area light and mesh emitter.
With light path on object emitter, set to “Is transmission Ray”, the object is hidden through window.
But for area light, with “Is transmission Ray”, light shape is still visible, and with “Transparent Depth”, we loose lighting on other objects.
Scene attached to play with it. [link](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/pbz2mm9d/)

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is to use the *Light Path node*.

This hides *transmission light* - when light goes through glass
But keeps *light dispersion* - when light is scattered inside glass/waterdrops/steam

*Example using a glass pane, Suzanne and a mesh light.

Note the light dispersion on the glass pane*

[image]

Comment: I tried this setup as well, but on Area Light, that didn't work. Great hint with mesh light. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Very helpful, I was looking for a solution for hours until I came across this thread. Thank you.

Although in my case I needed to add a Transparent node to the Backfacing of my mesh light as I was getting reflections on the glass material.